# MSVS2010 C++ Console Code Ported to MSVS2010 C++ GUI is Failing. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, libraries, libsndfile

I just completed a proof of concept, or so I thought, of feeding Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 some C++ code as a console program. The C++ code that compiled is given below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sndfile.h>


//The following libraries are related to parsing the text files
#include <iostream> //Open the file 
#include <fstream> //Reading to and from files



//The following libraries are for conducting the DTW analysis
#include "dtw.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("This is a test\n");


    //This will be the length of the buffer used to hold samples while the program processes them. 


    //A SNDFILE is like FILE in a standard C library. Consequently, the sf_open_read and sf_open_write functions will return an 
    //SNDFILE* pointer when they successfully open the specified file. 
    SNDFILE* sf = NULL; 

    /*SF_INFO will obtain information of the file we wish to load into our program. */
    SF_INFO info; 

    /*The following is descriptive information to obtain from wave files. These are declarations*/
    int num_channels;
    double num, num_items;S
    double *buf; 
    int f, sr, c; 
    int i,j;
    FILE *out; 


    /*This is where the program will open the WAV file */
    info.format = 0; 
    sf = sf_open("C:\\Users\\GeekyOmega\\Desktop\\gameon.wav", SFM_READ, &info);
    if(sf == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }

    /*Print some file information */
    f = info.frames;
    sr = info.samplerate;
    c = info.channels;

    /*Print information related to file*/
    printf("frames = %d\n",f);
    printf("sample rate = %d\n",sr);
    printf("channels = %d\n",c);

    /*Calculate and print the number of items*/  
    num_items = f*c;
    printf("Read %lf items\n", num_items);

    /*Allocate space for the data to be read*/
    buf = (double *) malloc(num_items*sizeof(double));
    num = sf_read_double(sf,buf,num_items);
    sf_close(sf);

    /*print the information*/
    printf("Read %lf items\n", num);



    /*Write the data to the filedata.out*/  
    out = fopen("filedata.txt", "w");
    for(i = 0; i < num; i+=c)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        {
            fprintf(out, "%lf ", buf[i +j]);
        }
        fprintf(out,"\n");
    }
    fclose(out);
```

}

So next, and this is critical, I want this to work with a GUI. That is, I load in any file I want and it converts that wav file to text. I provide that code below:

```
#pragma once
//Libraries required for libsndfile
#include <sndfile.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


namespace WaveGui {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;



    using namespace std;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
```

I edited this for readability. It was a standard MSVS2010 form. I only added a button and open file dialog.

```
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
             {

                if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
                 {  
                    //Note: Ask Gustafson how we might free the memory for this strign
                    //  http://support.microsoft.com/?id=311259

                    char* str2 = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(openFileDialog1->FileName);
                    SNDFILE* sf = NULL; 
                    SF_INFO info;

                    /*The following is descriptive information to obtain from wave files. These are declarations*/
                    int num_channels;
                    double num, num_items;
                    double *buf; 
                    int f, sr, c; 
                    int i,j;
                    FILE *out; 


                    /*This is where the program will open the WAV file */
                    info.format = 0; 
                    sf = sf_open(str2, SFM_READ, &info);
                    if(sf == NULL)
                    {
                        exit(-1);
                    }

                    /*Print some file information */
                    f = info.frames;
                    sr = info.samplerate;
                    c = info.channels;

                    /*Calculate and print the number of items*/  
                    num_items = f*c;

                    /*Allocate space for the data to be read*/
                    buf = (double *) malloc(num_items*sizeof(double));
                    num = sf_read_double(sf,buf,num_items);
                    sf_close(sf);

                    /*Write the data to the filedata.out*/  
                    out = fopen("filedata.txt", "w");
                    for(i = 0; i < num; i+=c)
                    {
                        for(j = 0; j < c; ++j)
                        {
                            fprintf(out, "%lf ", buf[i +j]);
                        }
                        fprintf(out,"\n");
                    }
                    fclose(out);



                 }




             }
    };
}
```

In the code for the button, I convert from a system string to regular string and then try to use the C++ code above to convert my wave file to txt information. I know the conversion code works, and I know the button code works as I have tested them separately. However, my library sndfile.h really dies when I try to use it now.

The error it gives me when I added the libraries stdio.h, Windows.H, stdlib.h, iostream, fstream is as follows:

```
1>WaveGui.obj : error LNK2031: unable to generate p/invoke for "extern "C" int __clrcall sf_close(struct SNDFILE_tag *)" (?sf_close@@$$J0YMHPAUSNDFILE_tag@@@Z); calling convention missing in metadata
1>WaveGui.obj : error LNK2031: unable to generate p/invoke for "extern "C" __int64 __clrcall sf_read_double(struct SNDFILE_tag *,double *,__int64)" (?sf_read_double@@$$J0YM_JPAUSNDFILE_tag@@PAN_J@Z); calling convention missing in metadata
1>WaveGui.obj : error LNK2031: unable to generate p/invoke for "extern "C" struct SNDFILE_tag * __clrcall sf_open(char const *,int,struct SF_INFO *)" (?sf_open@@$$J0YMPAUSNDFILE_tag@@PBDHPAUSF_INFO@@@Z); calling convention missing in metadata
1>WaveGui.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000027) for 'SNDFILE_tag'; image may not run
1>WaveGui.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000022) "extern "C" int __clrcall sf_close(struct SNDFILE_tag *)" (?sf_close@@$$J0YMHPAUSNDFILE_tag@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall WaveGui::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@WaveGui@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>WaveGui.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000023) "extern "C" __int64 __clrcall sf_read_double(struct SNDFILE_tag *,double *,__int64)" (?sf_read_double@@$$J0YM_JPAUSNDFILE_tag@@PAN_J@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall WaveGui::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@WaveGui@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>WaveGui.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000025) "extern "C" struct SNDFILE_tag * __clrcall sf_open(char const *,int,struct SF_INFO *)" (?sf_open@@$$J0YMPAUSNDFILE_tag@@PBDHPAUSF_INFO@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall WaveGui::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@WaveGui@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>WaveGui.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __clrcall sf_close(struct SNDFILE_tag *)" (?sf_close@@$$J0YMHPAUSNDFILE_tag@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall WaveGui::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@WaveGui@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>WaveGui.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" __int64 __clrcall sf_read_double(struct SNDFILE_tag *,double *,__int64)" (?sf_read_double@@$$J0YM_JPAUSNDFILE_tag@@PAN_J@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall WaveGui::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@WaveGui@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>WaveGui.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" struct SNDFILE_tag * __clrcall sf_open(char const *,int,struct SF_INFO *)" (?sf_open@@$$J0YMPAUSNDFILE_tag@@PBDHPAUSF_INFO@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall WaveGui::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@WaveGui@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>c:\users\geekyomega\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WaveGui\Debug\WaveGui.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

As near as I can tell, I installed the library right. After all, it works perfectly fine with these libraries in a console situation. However, when I try to use the exact same code and libraries with my GUI form, it seems that the libraries are not playing nice with each other and as a result, I can't read my .h file right and access structs like SNDFILE.

Can someone please let me know what is going wrong? I have spent hours on this and I hope I don't have to scrap the libsndfile library. I really want to get it to work with MSVS2010, with the GUI and as far as I can tell, there is no reason this shouldn't be working. But you know what they say, computers don't lie.

As always, thanks for your patient help. 
GeekyOmega

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your console app is native code, but your GUI app is managed C++. Was that intentional, or did you intend for your GUI app to be native (Win32) code too?

I think you'll have better luck if you either go with 100% native code, or perhaps create a DLL to encapsulate your native code and call that via P/Invoke from your .NET GUI.  Here's an example of using P/Invoke:

http://manski.net/2012/05/29/pinvoke-tutorial-basics-part-1/

Comment: Managed C++? I didn't choose that on purpose. I used this native C++ code with the idea of testing it to port over to a GUI. So, I selected the windows form option instead of the console in MSVS2010 in the wizard. Is there a way to use 100% native code in a MSVS GUI without the weird problems I am having? If so, I'll do that.

Comment: To go 100% native, choose the "Win32 Project" template when creating a New Project.  Then, when the Win32 Application Wizard appears, make sure the "Windows application" radio button is selected.  If you haven't done Win32 development before, there will be a learning curve.

Comment: Would you mind to take a look at this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654914/implementing-extern-winapi-call-in-mfc-c-app please