# Implementing extern WINAPI call in MFC C++ App

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, extern

I am working with ***Windows Form App C++***.
I have to use some header file that has

```
HRESULT extern WINAPI StartUp ( DWORD dwVRequired, LPVERSION lpVersion);
```

I have to execute this method within **Form1.h**

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    APPVERSION version;
    HRESULT result = APPStartUp(APP_VERSIONS, &version);
}
```

But I am getting the compile error like this

> Error 1   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000025) "extern "C" long
>   __stdcall APPStartUp(unsigned long,struct _version *)" (?WFSStartUp@@$$J18YGJKPAU_wfsversion@@@Z) referenced in function
>   "private: void __clrcall MyAppPresenter::Form1::Form1_Load(class
>   System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)"
>   (?Form1_Load@Form1@MyAppPresenter@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)  C:\Projects\MyAppPresenter\MyAppPresenter\MyAppPresenter.obj    MyAppPresenter

I assume it has something to do with 
[MSVS2010 C++ Console Code Ported to MSVS2010 C++ GUI is Failing. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189650/msvs2010-c-console-code-ported-to-msvs2010-c-gui-is-failing-why)

But how it can be done?
Any clue how it could be fixed?

Comment: You need to link with library (`.lib` file) where unresolved function is implemented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

I checked the console C++ project and found that ***.vsxproj** has

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Library Include="C:\Program Files\Common Files\GCFApp\lib\msmanager.lib" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So I just added this code to the Windows Form C++ project file manually and now it works.

Anyway I have no clue how to add it using GUI of VS 2010.